# How do I save the VM login/password in a VMware Remote Console desktop shortcut?

Tags: windows, password, login, vmware-server

I'm running VMware Server 2 and have created Virtual Machine Shortcuts for our various VMs. How do I save the VM login/password so I don't need to enter it each time I launch the shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "-u username" and "-p password" to the command-line shortcut to pass a username and password to the program.

Be sure not to use to -M option to reference the VM ID as this breaks the username/password feature.  Use the datastore path to the VMX instead

Comment: Hmm, didn't work. I still get the "Authenticate" window with an empty Username and Pasword field.

Comment: Okay, looks like you have to add the -u and -p options *immediately after* the -h option.

Comment: BUT, it's now reporting "Login failed due to a bad username or password". I'm sure they are correct, though -- I use the same values in the login window.

Comment: I've tried putting the values in quotes, and also prefixing my username with DOMAIN\ (it is my domain login). No luck still.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks to this thread: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/156057;jsessionid=6BCB0C353A8391DF303A1C01DF510395?start=15&tstart=0

In addition to putting the -u and -p options immediately after the -h option, I had to remove the [-M <id>] option from the shortcut, and put the datastore path to the vmx file, like this: "[datastore] VMDir/VMFile.vmx"

Comment: @Kevin Kuphal: If you can update your answer text with the additional info from my comments, or upvote my comments, I'll accept it.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the information

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Shortcut and select properties. change the properties so that it looks like below:

"D:\Program Files\Common Files\VMware\VMware Remote Console Plug-in\vmware-vmrc.exe" -h vmhost:8333 -u  -p   "[Vmware-01] VS2005-XP/VS2005-XP.vmx"